# 1 of 4 lights damaged on a ceiling fan

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, ceiling-fan, fire-hazard, light-bulb

[image]My ceiling fan has 4 lights. One of them popped last night and the glass came off but the screw part was still in there. I tried to remove it but ended up damaging the fixtures screw in part (real bad). I can’t find any thing on the web about if I can just remove that light or replace it.
Can I still use the fan part? Or the other 3 lights with out cause a fire from the broken one?

Comment: Type of light bulbs?  It should be simple to just cap/wire nut the loose wires and just use three lights, but will need pictures on how the fixtures are wired.  LED type might be harder.

Comment: Enclude a few pictures of the fixture so we can see what you see.  Damaged fixtures still have live wires in them so it needs to be fixed. The fan part can still be used.

Comment: pic are better at letting us understand your situation more completely.   If there is part of a broken bulb still in the socket, that is dangerous .  (Not imminent fire), but it should be corrected before using the fan.  Again ,pics will give better results from answers.

Comment: Thank you, added a pic

Answer (score 4):

In many light fixtures it is possible to replace the bulb socket with an equivalent new socket. These sockets are available, as in this non-endorsed example from a web-search:

[image: lamp socket replacement parts]

https://www.bplampsupply.com/category/172_lamp-sockets-cord-lamp-switches-plugs

Get a good look at one of the remaining sockets, perhaps even disassembling the socket out of the fixture so you can see the full socket, then web-search for an equivalent replacement. If electrical work is beyond your skills, a local friend who can do electrical work safely can help.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that got pretty gnarly.

You may be able to replace the entire light fixture.  There are a few different mounting types.

Google "Fan light kits"  for your brand of fan. You very possibly will find a replacement.